# jQuery UI Datepicker conditional mess.. is there a cleaner way to do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm setting up something of an "appointment" scheduler using the [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker), but I have a few conditions that I needed to implement:

- Customer could not schedule on a Sunday
- Customer can't schedule after 12pm on Saturday (have not implemented this)
- Can't schedule *next day* if the current time is past 12pm
- Can't schedule massively in advance (I chose +2 months)
- Can't schedule for the current day (and obviously not the past)

Here is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function noSundays(date) {
        return [date.getDay() != 0, ''];
    }
    var timezone = "EST";
    $.getJSON("http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz="+timezone+"&callback=?",
    function(data){
        if (data.hour < 12) {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
            beforeShowDay: noSundays,
            minDate: '+1d',
            maxDate: '+2m' });
        } else {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
            beforeShowDay: noSundays,
            minDate: '+2d',
            maxDate: '+2m' });
        }
    })
});
```

So we set noSundays, get the current time in EST from the JSON server and if it's before 12PM we fire up .datepicker with minDate : +1d (tomorrow), if it's after 12PM we use minDate : +2d. This code *works* but I feel like I'm doing something really wrong.  I'm still relatively inexperienced and would love to know if there is a better way to write this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be shorter like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timezone = "EST";
    $.getJSON("http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz="+timezone+"&callback=?",
      function(data){
        var parms = { 
          beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            return [date.getDay() != 0, ''];
          },
          minDate: '+2d',
          maxDate: '+2m' }
        if (data.hour < 12) {
          parms.minDate= '+1d';
          parms.maxDate= '+2m';
        }
        $("#datepicker").datepicker(parms);
      })
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, this was certainly a simpler solution.